# regedit export in php

Tags: php, registry, export

I am working on Windows XP.

Suppose I have already create a new key `lyon` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` in registry. Then I run the following script in php:

`exec("regedit /e c:/lyon.reg HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\lyon");`

well, nothing happens, though I can run the same thing in command prompt and get result expected.

am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec("REGEDIT /E c:\lyon.REG HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\lyon");
```

Comment: Is there any difference to use uppercase than lowercase? I tried your script, not working, my friend.

Comment: Hmm, never worked with exec or regedit. Look at this maybe it helps you! http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php

Comment: thanks. I already read your reference link hundred of times, actually if I run `exec("regedit /e c:/lyon.reg HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software");`, I can get result file as expected, but not deeper. I have no clue what went wrong, it seems to be permission problem, but I checked that I have full permissions on it. :(